# django utf-8 normalization

Tags: django, slug

Greetings

I want to slugify/normalize utf8 string however I get

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-   
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify
print slugify( unicode("şşşşüüüüççç") )
```

and get result as `"ssssuuuccc"`, however I get `UnicodeDecodeError 'ascii' codec cant decode ...` error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`unicode()` without an encoding argument tries to use ASCII to decode the given byte string, as a fail-safe default. `unicode("şşşşüüüüççç")` can't work as the string is not ASCII.

Use a unicode string literal:

```
print slugify(u"şşşşüüüüççç")
```

(and of course ensure that your text editor saves the script file using the UTF-8 encoding.)